# Reading value from a cell & code alignment

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, excel-2016, excel-automation

I have been trying to fetch api data from a web service in the past couple of days. I am unable to do it in a more efficient way and I am not getting help on my request too. After trying for long, I somehow have managed to get it from Excel Power Query (ver 2016) by recording a macro. However, I have two queries to be addressed and need help.

1. I have saved Unique ID in range D1 (1152843) and api key in range D2 (rrWedCKeclf1GqiY0pCBy05mdd). I have recorded a macro and want to supply the cell value within the code so that whenever the Unique ID or api key is changed, I dont have to change it in the code. I tried `range(d1).value` but the syntax is so long with so many quotation marks I am getting confused. Please help me edit that line.
2. The recorded macro is very big with some unnecessary stuff that needs to be removed and also it is very lengthy where I need to scroll horizontally to read the entire line. It becomes difficult for a beginner like me to understand this layout. Please help me align the code so that it can be in a readable format.

PS: Please run the code, see the result and suggest if there is a better way to do it that fetches the same result. Appreciate if I could get some suggestions.

Thanks

```
Public apiKey As String
Public matchID As String
Sub Macro5()

    Range("$A$4").Select

    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="Teams", Formula:= _
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents(""https://cricapi.com/api/fantasySummary?apikey=" & "rrWedCKeclf1GqiY0pCBy05mdd" & "&unique_id=" & "1152843""))," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    data = Source[data]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    team = data[team]," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Converted to Table"" = Table.FromList(team, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Ignore)," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Renamed Columns"" = Table.RenameColumns(#""Converted " & _
        "to Table"",{{""Column1"", ""Teams""}})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Teams"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Renamed Columns"", ""Teams"", {""players"", ""name""}, {""Teams.players"", ""Teams.name""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Teams.players"" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#""Expanded Teams"", ""Teams.players"")," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Expanded Teams.players1"" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#""Expanded Teams.pl" & _
        "ayers"", ""Teams.players"", {""name"", ""pid""}, {""Teams.players.name"", ""Teams.players.pid""})," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordered Columns"" = Table.ReorderColumns(#""Expanded Teams.players1"",{""Teams.name"", ""Teams.players.pid"", ""Teams.players.name""})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Reordered Columns"""

        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=Teams;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$4")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [Teams]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "Teams"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

    Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Teams").TableStyle = ""

    Range("$A$4").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: If all you need is to use cell values as parameters in your query there is no need for VBA. Checkout my answer on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56450594/excel-how-to-change-the-rest-url-based-on-the-cell-parameters/56462757#56462757).